# nginx as reverse proxy for runining apache

Tags: linux, nginx, apache2, kloxo

I have some trouble configuring `nginx` as reverse proxy.

It is good to say I have a VPS with `kloxo` and `webmin` installed and running multiple domains on my VPS.

I have installed `nginx` via `REPEL` and `YUM` and this is my `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file 
given in this [link](http://pastebin.com/2yCndm6B).

I change apache port to 8080 and restart service for making changes and start nginx and there is some problem.

When I try reaching every domains on my centos vps, I face to `APACHE START PAGE (WELCOME PAGE)` and when I enter my VPS IP in browser like `x.x.x.x`, I face to `NGINX START PAGE (WELCOME PAGE)`.

I want `nginx` to serve my static files and redirect dynamic ones to `Apache` for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example from the book Nginx Http Server, page 235.

```
server {
    server_name .example.com;
    root /home/example.com/www;
    location ~* \.php.$ {
        # Proxy all requests with an URI ending with .php*
        # (includes PHP, PHP3, PHP4, PHP5...)
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
    location / {
        # Your other options here for static content
        # for example cache control, alias...
        expires 30d;
    }
}
```